# What's the purpose of `tunegrid` in the caret package?

Tags: classification, predictive-models, caret

I am deciding the parameters for a random forest classification model. I am using the caret package and read, [here](https://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html#the-traincontrol-function), about the tuning grid. My understanding is that it helps determine the best values for the tuning parameters, like `mtry` and `n.trees`.

Isn't that redundant to `trControl`? As I understand it, if I set trControl to `trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 3)`, then it will re-run the model three times with ten-fold cross validation to find the best values for the tuning parameters.

If that's true, then what purpose does `tunegrid` serve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, caret will estimate a tuning grid for each method. However, sometimes the defaults are not the most sensible given the nature of the data. The tuneGrid argument allows the user to specify a *custom* grid of tuning parameters as opposed to simply using what exists implicitly.